# Pycaret plot_model() visualize graph not properly

Tags: python, pycaret

When I used plot_model() on Pycaret in Colabs, I got unusable graph like this.

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahXfL.png)

How I can use zoom slicing on my graph like this? They just using normal plot_model() and got zoom slicing feature.

[Zoom slicing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nIjv.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the [GitHub repo discussions](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/discussions/2372). Summarizing here again:

When you have too many data points, the interactivity is disabled (because they cause the notebook to freeze). However, you can manually enable interactivity if you that is what you want..

Please refer to [this notebook](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/time_series/forecasting/customizing_experiments.ipynb) for details: Section Setting Renderer.

You can also refer to the docstring in setup or plot_model for more details.

Bottomline: You can override the renderer to be "notebook", or "colab" or any other interactive renderer for any plot (in `plot_model`) or globally (in `setup`).

Comment: notebook link is dead

Comment: updated the notebook link now. Please have a look.